# i'm tring to read data from firestore in recyclerview but its not showing and not giving any error. but showing data in toast

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

i want data in recyclerview but it's not showing there but when i try to pass data in toast it shows data there i don't know why.
i've tried firebaseui but it also didn't worked

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'

implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.1'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
```

}

Here is my main class in which i want the data.

```
public class createdplaylist extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    palylistadapter  palylistadapter;
    Context context;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;

    @Override


  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createdplaylist, container, false);

context=container.getContext();
   firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query=firestore.collection("playlist");
recyclerView =view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerr);


query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable 
    FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
          for(DocumentSnapshot ds: value.getDocuments()){
              str.add(ds.getId());
              Toast.makeText(context, ds.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
     });
      palylistadapter=new palylistadapter(context,str);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(palylistadapter);
     return view;

    }
```

my adapter class

```
   public class palylistadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<palylistadapter.viewhold> {

Context context;
ArrayList<String>list;

public palylistadapter( Context c,ArrayList<String>s){
this.list=s;
    this.context=c;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public viewhold onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.playlistlayout,parent,false);
viewhold viewhold=new viewhold(v);
return viewhold;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewhold holder, int position) {

    holder.t.setText(list.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(list.isEmpty())
   return 0;
    else
        return list.size();
}
public class viewhold extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView t;
    public viewhold(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
      t=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textname);

    }
}
```

}

//ignor this part
mdgxbjkdbjvz
zdjxcvbfxbcnbmxcbz
gvjbvxkbvmxnvbzxv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting anything inside your RecylerView, because you're reading data from Firestore but you aren't informing the adapter that you have added the objects to the list. So to solve this, you have to rearrange the code and call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) right after the for loop ends:

```
palylistadapter=new palylistadapter(context,str);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(palylistadapter);
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable
    FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds: value.getDocuments()){
            str.add(ds.getId());
            Toast.makeText(context, ds.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        palylistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //                
    }
});
```